# Zybooks 6.18 LAB: Track laps to miles

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science

So I have written the code correctly for this problem, but I don't understand a part of the code that was already present as a requirement to use. What does this part of the code do?:
`if __name__ == '__main__':`

---

The problem prompt is:

One lap around a standard high-school running track is exactly 0.25 miles. Define a function named laps_to_miles that takes a number of laps as a parameter, and returns the number of miles. Then, write a main program that takes a number of laps as an input, calls function laps_to_miles() to calculate the number of miles, and outputs the number of miles.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
print(f'{your_value:.2f}')

Ex:
If the input is:
7.6 -->
the output is:
1.90

Ex:
If the input is:
2.2 -->
the output is:
0.55

The program must define and call the following function:
def laps_to_miles(user_laps)

---

My code is:

```
def laps_to_miles(user_laps):
    user_miles = user_laps*0.25
    return user_miles
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_laps = float(input())
    print(f'{laps_to_miles(user_laps):.2f}')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def miles_to_laps(user_miles):
    miles_to_laps = user_miles *4
    return miles_to_laps

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    user_miles = float(input())
    print(f'{laps_to_miles(user_laps):.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def laps_to_miles(user_laps):
    user_miles = user_laps*4
    return user_miles
def miles_to_laps(user_miles):
    miles_to_laps = user_miles *4
    return miles_to_laps
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_laps = float(input())
    print(f'{laps_to_miles(user_laps):.2f}')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

````
def laps_to_miles(user_laps):
    user_miles = user_laps/4
    return user_miles
def miles_to_laps(user_miles):
    miles_to_laps = user_miles /4
    return miles_to_laps
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_laps = float(input())
    print(f'{laps_to_miles(user_laps):.2f}')```
````

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Define your function here
def laps_to_miles(user_laps):

    num_lap = user_laps*0.25
    return float(num_lap)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #you need to state the input within the print statment also the if statment dosent need to be changed it will work.
    print(f'{laps_to_miles(float(input())):.2f}')
```

hope this helps :)